# Show message if inserted successfully PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

I wrote some PHP code to insert the records in to MySQL database. I want to display a message indicating whether the records are successfully added to the database or not. I tried several times but I failed.

**Code:**

```
<?php
try {
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = 'cea123';
    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=symposium', $db_user, $db_pass );
    $form = $_POST;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO app ( 
            firstname, lastname, company, homepage, contactno, addressline1, addressline2, city,
          postalcode, country, email,  abstractdetails ) 
            VALUES ( 
            :firstname, :lastname, :company, :homepage, :contactno, :addressline1, :addressline2,
         :city,   :postalcode, :country, :email, :abstractdetails )";
    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute( array( ':firstname'=>$firstname, ':lastname'=>$lastname, ':company'=>$company, ':homepage'=>$homepage, ':contactno'=>$contactno, ':addressline1'=>$addressline1, ':addressline2'=>$addressline2, ':city'=>$city, ':postalcode'=>$postalcode, ':country'=>$country, ':email'=>$email,  ':abstractdetails'=>$abstractdetails ));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check simply  using [*rowCount*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function,

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0){
  echo "Record Inserted Successfully !!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you never print out a Text that show you that your Insert was succesfull.

```
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

will only show you the error, if one appeard.

To print a text that will show you that it was succesfull you have to insert at the end of the try block (before your catch block)

```
 try {

     [...]
   if($query->rowCount() > 0){
     echo "Record Inserted Successfully !!";
   }
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   [...]
 }
```